# Why is this css taking precedent?

Tags: css

I have a textbox that i added a class (ui-state-error) to add a border color: #CD0A0A but its not working.  I realized that some other css is trumping it:

```
textarea, input[type="text"], select {
    border: 1px solid #B5B8C8;
}

.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
     background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #FEF1EC;
   border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
   color: #CD0A0A;
}
```

is there anyway i can add a class "ui-state-error" to a textbox and have that border css override the input[type="text"] border css.

I thought because it was below in my css that it would trump the above?

Comment: Can you try textarea.ui-state-error { /* CSS here */ }?

Comment: FYI `The attribute selector overrides the class selector, the child selector, the adjacent sibling selector, the descendant selector and the type selector`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The later ordering of CSS rules "trumps" *when* (and only when) the selectors have the *same* [Selector Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity).

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> 1. count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
> 2. count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> 3. count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
> 4. ignore the universal selector

In this case, the specificity is

```
input[type="text"]   -> a=0 b=1 c=1 -> 11  --winner, order doesn't matter
.ui-state-error      -> a=0 b=1 c=0 -> 10
```

Now, *if* the later selector rule also included a type selector

```
input[type="text"]   -> a=0 b=1 c=1 -> 11 
input.ui-state-error -> a=0 b=1 c=1 -> 11  --winner, by ordering override
```

Comment: can you clarify why the first item has two 1's ?

Comment: @leora I added the `x=..` so you can see which rule was applied. After a, b, and c are determined then (trivially) they can be thought of as being concatenated into a number, where the higher number wins.

Comment: why does the first item have b=1 ?

Comment: @leora "count the number of .. attributes selectors .. (= b)", from `[type=text]`.

Comment: @leora I've added an example of how to adjust the specificity for this case such that ordering does apply.

Comment: You shouldn't use `input.class`, that will apply to passwords, and buttons as well, consider using `input[type=text]`

Comment: @Mr.Alien That's a valid argument, but it messes up the pretty numbers :| I'll leave my answer the same, but upvote your comment for better visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your second CSS rule is more specific that your first CSS rule.

You can

- add `!important` to the first one, which is generally a bad idea, or
- make it more specific.

As commends and other answers have suggested `textarea.some-class` might work, but even better, you can try:

```
.parents-class textarea.some-class {...}
```

The more specific you get, the less likely it is that your rule will be ignored.

Comment: You shouldn't use `!important` unles required

Comment: The only acceptable use I've ever found for `!important` is testing. If adding it changes something, I remove it and move on to something more reliable in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. add !important after the property you want to be applied to the input 
   Ex: `border: 1px solid #CD0A0A !important;  color: #CD0A0A !important;`
2. Use id (which have a high priority in css). Ex: #ui_error, .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content ...

and the input will be like this

```
<input type="text" id="ui_error">
```